# Tasker Action not triggering outside the app

Tags: android, automation, tasker

I just picked up tasker and tried to create a task where when a certain notification like Ringing occurs, notification is clicked and the app is openend.

So, this is the event and action

```
Profile: Door Bell
Event: AutoNotification Intercept [ Configuration:Event Behaviour: true
Notification Type: Only Created Notifications
Notification Apps: eufy Security
Notification Text: the door was unlocked manually (case ins) ]

Enter Task: Anon

A1: Wait [
MS: 300
Seconds: 0
Minutes: 0
Hours: 0
Days: 0 ]

A2: Flash [
Text: Number 1
Continue Task Immediately: On
Dismiss On Click: On ]

A3: AutoNotification Actions [
Configuration: Notification Apps: eufy Security
Intercept Action ID: %antouchaction
Timeout (Seconds): 20
Structure Output (JSON, etc): On ]

A4: Flash [
Text: Number 2
Continue Task Immediately: On
Dismiss On Click: On ]
```

The issue is that when I am on the home screen of my phone and trigger the notification, nothing happens other than the `Flash` action, but when I am on the `AutoNotification`  action's configuration screen and trigger the notification, the app also gets opened.

I checked all the settings and enabled everything, but idk why this is happen..
I really appreciate the help in advance.